# Enable HA/High Replication option in GAE app

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven

I'm getting this error when trying to do `Transaction` within my application:

```
transactions on multiple entity groups only allowed in High Replication applications
```

With the Google Plugin for Eclipse, its easy to enable HA option; however when running with the GAE maven archetype: `mvn gae:run`

Not sure how to make HA enabled with maven. How can I enable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a doc on this here.  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/devserver#Simulating_the_High_Replication_ConsistencyModel

That said, I'm not familiar with the kindleit gae plugin's configuration.  To enable this in the official plugin, you would add this to your pom:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
    <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.6</version>
    <configuration>
      <jvmFlags>
        <jvmFlag>-Ddatastore.default_high_rep_job_policy_unapplied_job_pct=20</jvmFlag>
      </jvmFlags>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to migrate your application into HR.

1. Open the Administration Console, select the application you want to copy, and go to Application Settings.
2. In the New Application Identifier text box, notice that your current application's application ID is shown with the -hrd suffix. You can use this or provide an entirely new application ID if you wish.
3. Click Check Availability to verify that the application ID you've chosen is available. Change the ID if necessary.
4. Click Duplicate Application.

And then you need to use your new application identifier. You can't migrate from Master/Slave to HR without changing application ID.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/migration

Comment: You are describing the GAE in Appspot.com version, I am talking about the local runtime, that is, the local SDK...